# way to express that tube got fused

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

Consider the context - when I am on a video call with someone and the tube got fused so it all 
became dark and the other person couldn't see me.

Is saying - `The tube is gone` correct English. What's the better way to express this at the time

Comment: By "tube", do you mean fluorescent light tube?  Idiomatically, we usually don't refer to this as a "tube" unless we're handling it directly (e.g., replacing it).  It's better to say, "The lights went out."

Comment: yeah the  fluorescent light tube. But in this case it's only the  fluorescent light tube that malfunctioned. So is it appropriate to say lights went out ? That sounds like the total electricity went out

Comment: If you wanted to emphasize that it's only one light, you could say, "The light burnt out."

Answer (score 1):

"fused" is generally used for when some solid is bonded to another solid.  I think you're used to using "fused" in the way we would say "broken"

Fluorescent lights use plasma gas to make their light, so saying a fluorescent light is "fused" is even more confusing.

"Tube" is generally used for a hollow cylinder, or perhaps an old style television cathode ray tube.  We no longer use cathode ray tubes in our displays, so referring to them might work; but, only in a historical sense.  I might be able to say "there's something on the tube" but it would only apply to television in my region, as in my region, "the tube" is slang for "television".  This is because computers were not nearly as popular or accessible during the time that people had cathode ray tube televisions.

In your case, using less slang probably would help you a lot.

> The fluorescent light broke in my display

Would express exactly what you wanted to say, in a way that would not rely on slang.